# ubuntu 18 Hangs on logo then black screen

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, freeze

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on an [Inspiron E1705 PC](http://www.dell.com/content/topics/topic.aspx/global/products/inspn/topics/en/inspn_e1705_sp_spec?c=us&l=en&cs=19).

It seems to install correctly (I've tried multiple times on dvd-r and on usb) but when I restart It is doing two things:

1. It hangs when starting up at the ubuntu screen (the scrolling dots freeze in place) after a minute or so, then the screen turns off completely (not just black but no backlighting or anything) and neither mouse clicks nor button presses do anything. I eventually have to press and hold the power button to get it to turn off.
2. I ran advanced options for it, but whatever I do it hangs on 
   `[ OK ] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switches.` 
   Anyone know whats going on here? I'm trying to do a complete reset and install, it had KODIOS on it before, Windows 10 and Ubuntu before that.

**MAJOR EDIT:** When I run Ubuntu in recovery mode but just select `Resume Normal Boot` it works fine. So I can boot into it but only when selecting this option. How can I fix the regular version?

*Note: I used the Freeze tag even though it says do not use, because the actualy install is freezing not any installed software. Should I remove it? :P*

Comment: Nvidia graphics card?

Comment: No nothing fancy.

Comment: Try researching - nomodeset quiet splash

Comment: Mk ty, I’ll look into it

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, with travel I didnt have the computer to test with until today. That worked. Can you post that as an answer? This worked: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

On some older video hardware configurations, you may need to set kernel parameters for Ubuntu to boot or work properly. A common one is nomodeset, which is needed for some graphics cards (most commonly NVIDIA) that otherwise boot into a black screen or corrupted splash.

To check if you have an Nvidia graphics card:

```
lspci | grep -i nvidia
```

or check your video adapter type:

```
lspci | grep vga
```

At boot up press <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Escape</kbd> during boot while GRUB is loading to get the menu.

Press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit the first kernel displayed.
On the line ending with a quiet splash. Add the boot option `nomodeset quiet splash`

Then press CTRL + X to boot

Lots of further reading links on the net regarding Nvidia and nomodeset.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

[How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)